# jQuery: create variables from min and max values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create jquery variables using min and max values.

To explain what i am trying to do I've created this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sLe6Lpyg/)

and this is my entire code:

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(".allPro").each(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        if (isNaN(price)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price;}
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price;}


    });
    return [min, max];
    var maximum = max;
    var minimum = min;
}

alert(minimum);
```

when i run my code, i get no `alert();` at all and when i look in the console, i get `minimum is undifined`

could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not calling the function in the first place

Comment: @JoshHarington, sorry, not sure what you mean! could you please elaborate?

Comment: The maximum and minimum variables are only created after the return, which mean they wont run. But they are created INSIDE the function which means they have a local scope and not available from outside the `minMaxId()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call function `minMaxId` and assign result to variable ans then use it

```
function minMaxId(selector) {
    var min=null, max=null;
    $(".allPro").each(function() {
        var price = parseInt($(this).attr("data-price"), 10);
        if (isNaN(price)) { return; }
        if ((min===null) || (price < min)) { min = price;}
        if ((max===null) || (price > max)) { max = price;}


    });

    return [min, max];
}

var result = minMaxId();
var maximum = result[1];
var minimum = result[0];

console.log(minimum);
console.log(maximum);
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/sLe6Lpyg/1/)

Because in your variant function return value and you are trying assign variables after return, also you are using `var` - in this case this variables will be only in function scope